# Line Integral in Octave

Tags: line-integrals, symbolic-computation, octave

I want to compute Line Integral in Octave. There is a [sample code](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1436619-how-can-i-compute-line-integral-problem-in-matlab) that works fine in Matlab, but it does not work in Octave.

```
syms F1(x,y) F2(x,y) r1(t) r2(t)
r1(t) = cos(t)+2;
r2(t) = sin(t);
F1(x,y) = -y;
F2(x,y) = x;
r = [r1;r2];
F = [F1;F2];
Fr = F(r1(t),r2(t)); % error: subscript indices must be integers or boolean
```

How can I fix that? If Octave can not compute this, is there any other framework (free) where I could compute this?

Comment: There are problem some syntax differences. I would recommend asking chatgpt to help you fix the code first

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to fix this.